# Why Observable.ToEnumerable() does not produce values until underlying sequence completes?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Running the following code

```
    foreach(var i in
    Observable
        .Range(1, 3)
        .Do(Console.WriteLine)
        .ToEnumerable())
        Console.WriteLine("Fin:" + i);
```

I'm getting this output:

```
1
2
3
Fin:1
Fin:2
Fin:3
```

The question is - why does ToEnumerable caches all the values and provides them just after the source sequence completes?
Does it related somehow to "leaving the monad"?

Comment: Why would it do different? What are you expecting but a sequential execution of your code?

Comment: I expected the following:
1 Fin:1, 2 Fin:2, 3 Fin:3
...

Comment: Try `Observable.Range(0, 3).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)`. that shows `ToEnumerable` doesn't block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig into the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive) of the Rx library you'll see that the `ToEnumerable` operator is implemented basically like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    using var enumerator = new GetEnumerator<T>();
    enumerator.Run(source);
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) yield return enumerator.Current;
}
```

...where the `GetEnumerator<T>` is a class defined in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/GetEnumerator.cs) file. This class is an `IEnumerator<T>` and an `IObserver<T>`. It has an internal `_queue` (`ConcurrentQueue<T>`) where it stores the received items. The most interesting methods are the `Run`, `OnNext` and `MoveNext`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> Run(IObservable<T> source)
{
    _subscription.Disposable = source.Subscribe(this);
    return this;
}

public void OnNext(T value)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(value);
    _gate.Release();
}

public bool MoveNext()
{
    _gate.Wait();
    if (_queue.TryDequeue(out _current)) return true;
    _error?.Throw();
    return false;
}
```

In your code, when you start the `foreach` loop, the `Run` method runs, and the `Range+Do` sequence is subscribed. This sequence emits all its elements during the subscription. The `OnNext` method is invoked for each emited element, so all elements are enqueued inside the `_queue`. After the completion of the `Run` method, follows the `while` loop that dequeues and yields the queued elements. That's why you see all the sideffects of the `Do` operator happening before any iteration of your `foreach` loop.

The Rx library includes another operator similar to the `ToEnumerable`, the `Next` operator, with this signature:

```
// Returns an enumerable sequence whose enumeration blocks until the next element
// in the source observable sequence becomes available. Enumerators on the resulting
// sequence will block until the next element becomes available.
public static IEnumerable<T> Next<T>(this IObservable<T> source);
```

According to my expirements this operator doesn't do what you want either.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually now it is clear why different Schedulers lead to different behavior - because of the blocking nature of Subscribe under Immediate scheduler

Answer (score 2):

`ToEnumerable` doesn't wait for observable to complete, it just happens that observable completes synchronously in this case. `Observable.Interval` shows this:

```cs
var enumerable =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Take(3)
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine("obs: {0}", i))
        .ToEnumerable();

foreach (int value in enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: So it is only scheduler-related? If I'm adding                 .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)

It starts to emit the values thru enumerable also, but does it in bulks.
I wonder - why ImmediateScheduler blocks ToEnumerable from emitting its values further?

Comment: @OlegDok, can't help with this. Never worked with schedulers in rx

Comment: actually I've found answer. [`ImmediateScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229588(v=vs.103)) block current thread, so control doesn't go to `ToEnumerable`  unless all `Do` are executed. `NewThreadScheduler` seems to produce values in bulks because it's start new thread, which should be stopped after handler is executed. PC have limitation of concurrently running threads